# puppeteer: How to set Value for a Input Element for REACT and Typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, react-hooks, automated-tests, puppeteer

I would like to test my app with Puppeteer.
I used REACT and TypeScript.
how can I set the input correctly? Please see the 2 attachments.

I try the following, but without success:

1.try:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#MuiButtonBase-root');
// await page.select('#MuiTouchRipple-root');
await page.waitForSelector('#name');
await page.type('#name', 'Hello');
```

2.try:

```
await page.$eval('#MuiDialogContent-root input:MuiFormControl-root:nth-child(1)', el => el.value = 'Hello');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the wrong selector. `#name` is the same as `[id="name"]` and you want `[name="name"]`

Use the 1st way for React or the onChange won't get triggered.